# How to save information in a button in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-button

I get JSON

```
{
"id_servicio": "1",
"id_motoboy": "1",
"nombre": "Juan Alexander",
"apellido": "Osorio Obreque",
"rut": "1111111",
"direccion": "Luis uribe 3690",
"telefono1": "1223214",
"comentario": "lorem ipsum",
"referencia": "Al lado del negocio Don Goyito",
"id_estado": "3",
"fecha_hora": "2015-01-13 19:51:27",
"created_at": "2015-01-13 17:51:27",
"updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
"productos": [
    {
        "id_producto": "1",
        "id_empresa": "1",
        "nombre": "Cuenta Rut",
        "descripcion": "Mayor de 18 años",
        "estado": "1",
        "created_at": "2015-01-13 13:04:00",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "pivot": {
            "id_servicio": "1",
            "id_producto": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "id_producto": "2",
        "id_empresa": "1",
        "nombre": "Chilena",
        "descripcion": "Sueldo mayor a 300.000.-",
        "estado": "1",
        "created_at": "2015-01-14 13:59:31",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
        "pivot": {
            "id_servicio": "1",
            "id_producto": "2"
        }
    }
]
```

}

So I create button in android with the information of `productos`

```
                   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(tmp.getString("productos"));
                Button bt[] = new Button[jsonArray.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i ++){
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    bt[i] = new Button(DetalleServicioActivity.this);
                    bt[i].setText(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"));
                    bt[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    bt[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#17498D"));
                    bt[i].setLayoutParams(params);
                    bt[i].setEnabled(false);
                    bt[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    });
                    rl.addView(bt[i]);

                }
```

What I need is to save the identifier(`id_producto`) from the product in the button, of such way to know that button were pressed (selected) by the user.

How can I do that??

Comment: Why don't you use the setId or setTag methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `btn.setTag(productId)` then `String productId = (String)btn.getTag()`

Answer (score 2):

You can extends Button to a new class.

```
public Class CustomButton extends Button {

// Write your own methods & logic here

}
```

Comment: Good answer but in this case I only need to save one data

Answer (score 0):

You can add id in the buttons tag (button[i].setTag(id)...) and in onClick(View v).. you can get the tag to verify which one is clicked by doing ((Button)view).getTag() // will return the id passed before

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in at least two ways:

1 Tag (it's a field where you can store custom data)

```
bt[i].setTag(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_producto"));
```

2 Closure (just pass the data to the listener)

```
bt[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String productId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id_producto");
    }
});
```